# Rsync - memory usage

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, rsync, memory-usage

I am running on Xubuntu 14.04 and experiencing high memory usage of rsync.

With a fresh start, the system is OK.

I have rsync running in a cronjob, after/during rsync memory usage increases and stays high (seems like rsync is not freeing the memory).

Any hints/suggestions/etc???

`rsync` command:

```bsh
sudo rsync -auAXv --delete --ignore-errors /* /media/edisz/backup_hdd/ --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}
```

Here's the `htop` output (after `rsync`):

[image: screenshot of terminal showing htop]

And `free -m` shows:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3816       3386        429         19        230       1000
-/+ buffers/cache:       2155       1660
Swap:         3954          0       3954
```

OK, firefox is eating ~400MB, but then there are still 1700MB left...

And before `rsync`:

[image: screenshot of terminal showing htop output before rsync]

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3816       1497       2318         39         71        731
-/+ buffers/cache:        694       3121
Swap:         3954          0       3954
```

Comment: The only explanation that comes to my mind would be a memory leak in the kernel or a kernel module, since otherwise the memory usage should be shown in top/htop. I had similar issues in 2009, which at that time were caused by a bug in the proprietary graphics driver. Since you link your issue to the use of rsync, in your case it might have something to do with the filesystem... In order to check how much RAM the kernel uses, have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97261/how-much-ram-does-the-kernel-use

Comment: @soulsource. Jupp, dropping caches after rsync seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropping caches after rsync seem to fix the problem:

```
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

See also [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rsync-hogs-memory-758345/).

Though, I do not find this very convenient....

Comment: EDi, Thanks a bunch! This is EXACTLY the issue I was having rsyncing large files at night. In the morning I would discover A lot of memory eaten away. Clearing caches after sync brings memory back to where it should be. I wish I found this earlier, I wouldn't have to reboot my workstation every morning :) I'll schedule this to run after sync is finished.

Comment: There is an relevant answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20817772/1005575).  Essentially, if you installing  `nocache`, you can simply prepend all your commands with `nocache`.  `nocache` is available through `apt` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `--no-inc-recursive` flag is also an option to reduce memory usage.
Disabling incremental recursion will reduce memory usage if you have many nested files.