# rsync is boiling and using all my memory

Tags: ram, rsync

When I backup a directory on my webhotel `rsync` eats all my memory. I have 8G of RAM and rsync eats it all - if not more, the other day nothing happened and I had to stop rsync with ctrl+C. After finishing the backup it takes about 8 hours before the memory use is down to around 1G.

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

The commands I have tried are:

```
rsync -a -v --progress --delete -c -i -s source destination_same_filesystem
```

Earlier I have also used

```
rsync -auvtz -e  source destination_same_filesystem
```

The source directory to backup contains 25G.

The log files I have access to have no information about the commands I use logged in with ssh.

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           41G        37G       3.3G       978M       2.3G        17G
-/+ buffers/cache:        17G        23G
Swap:         2.0G       580M       1.4G
```

and top:

```
top - 13:48:21 up 85 days, 23:18,  0 users,  load average: 1.26, 1.18, 1.31
Tasks:   4 total,   1 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  5.7%us,  5.6%sy,  0.2%ni, 87.3%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.5%st
Mem:  43112192k total, 39590280k used,  3521912k free,  2459892k buffers
Swap:  2097148k total,   594808k used,  1502340k free, 18420724k cached

    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 138887 kursista  20   0  408m  49m  41m S  2.3  0.1   0:02.50 php
 135318 kursista  20   0  108m 1900  904 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 sshd
 135319 kursista  20   0 11448 1768 1380 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash
 141205 kursista  20   0 14896 1172  956 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 top
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of `free -h` while `rsync` is running and "eating all your RAM" as you say? Probably you're just looking at the wrong number and what you think is "used" is actually just automatic disk cache managed by Ubuntu to speed up further reads to the same data on disk, as long as there is available RAM. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for a detailed explanation.

Comment: free -h gives

`free -h

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           41G        37G       3.3G       978M       2.3G        17G
-/+ buffers/cache:        17G        23G
Swap:         2.0G       580M       1.4G`

Sorry, I can't control formatting this

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to add that output? It's hardly readable in comments as it loses formatting there.

Comment: I do not have 41G, but the webhost server might have.

Comment: Hope that's better :)

Comment: Okay, so currently you have 3.3GB "useless" RAM. I say "useless" instead of "unused"  to make clear that nothing is done with them at the moment at all.  The remaining 37 GB are "used" - but not all of them are allocated to any specific application, because what the system labels as "used" includes also the disk cache and some other buffers etc. Disk cache however is only temporarily there and gets dropped immediately if any application requests more RAM. Therefore the available RAM for your applications is the 23 GB. That's fine.

Comment: Well, all that ram is not mine, it belongs to the webserver. I am on a shared server, I am only allowed to use 8G. It seems that when I use ssh the command line output is not only about my space on the server. It is in cpanel I can se my mem use

Comment: I don't know how your system is set up and have never worked with anything like that, but if the system reports it controls 41 GB of RAM and has 37 GB of them in use, then you're obviously not limited to 8 GB. Except your host is using some kind of virtualization solution where guest and host resources get mixed up somehow... no idea bout such things though.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found [Rsync - memory usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465651/rsync-memory-usage?rq=1), that suggest me to use

```
sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Unfortunately: Permission denied
so I better contact the webhotel to get this fixed.